# React set focus to grandchild in parent child grandchild hierarchy

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have a classic parent->child->grandchild hierarchy of `React` components. When I click on a link in the parent I want to set focus to a textbox in the grandchild component.

My first attempt was to pass a `callback` function through the `props` of the parent and then the child and then finally the grandchild. The grandchild then called the callback, passing its `ref` property to the callback. That reference was then stored by the parent component so that when the link was clicked in the parent it could use `getDOMNode` of the referenced grandchild component and simply call `focus()` to set its focus. This configuration worked.

But I wan't happy with having to pass the callback via a `prop` in the child component. The child component had no need for that `prop` and was simply passing it on to the grandchild. AFAIK this is a classic `React` problem. What if sometime later I added another level to the hierarchy between child and grandchild, I'd have to remember to
make it pass the `prop` down as well (and change my tests!).

I then thought, could the `FLUX` pattern help me here? Wasn't one of the advantages of `FLUX` to decouple the dependencies between these hierarchical structures? I'm already using `ReFlux` as part of this application so why don't I use that. As the child component mounts it could place its `ref` value to the `ReFlux` store and when the parent link is clicked it grabs the value from the store and calls `.focus` on it.

Then I realized that I'm actually rendering a list. So one item in the list consists of parent->child->grandchild and then the next item in the list consists of another parent->child->grandchild, etc... The problem is that `FLUX` stores are singletons. So as each grandchild is rendered it would pass it's `ref` value to the store and overwrite the previous one. Then I thought ok, I'll use an array of items in the store, that way I can store the `ref` of each grandchild and when the link is clicked in a parent it can look up the corresponding grandchild in the array and set focus to it.

My question is, (finally we're getting there :)

1. Is this a reasonably approach?
2. Should I be using `FLUX` stores for this kind of behavior? i.e. storing `ref` values in a `FLUX` store?

Comment: I'd probably just centralize the problem using a simple global event manager. Passing refs around breaks encapsulation. Focus is not really state, as it's just set and forget. Fire off an event with a unique Id that one of the focusable children can listen for uniquely.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the problem correctly, but I don't see why you can't just pass something down from grandparent to parent to child?  For example in the case of multiple grandchildren, just referencing them by id.  Such as grandparent telling parent via a prop like `focusChild={3}`, the parent then reacting to that prop and sending a prop like `forceFocus` to the child which in turn checks for that prop on `componentWillReceiveProps` and calls `this.getDOMNode().focus()` ?